# NodeJS MongoDB driver API for listing database users

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm reading through the documentation on the [MongoDB Driver for NodeJS](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html) and can see that the `DB` object has methods for adding and removing database users, but nothing obvious for listing or modifying them.

For reference - I'm trying to perform something similar to a command like this that works from the Mongo shell

```
use mydatabase
db.getUsers()
```

Am I missing documentation that is inside another object? Perhaps a hacky workaround is possible (maybe `eval`?). Or is this operation simply not possible with the NodeJS driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use db.command function

```
    var getCmdResult = function(db,command_object,callback) {
          db.command(command_object,
          function(err, results) {
            console.log(results);
            callback();
        }
      );
    };

    // use the function
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient


    // Connection URL
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test';
    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

// getting users info, equivalent to mongoshell db.getUsers() 
    var cmd = {usersInfo: 1 };
      console.log("Connected correctly to server");
      getCmdResult(db,cmd function() {
        db.close();
      });
    });
```

Please refer this for more details on available commands:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/

Comment: Is this function meant to be used as a catch-all for the "we didn't make this an explicit part of the API" operations? I know `eval` is deprecated which I'm guessing is similar but more expressive and open in scope.